# Regular expression to check url and shared file path

Tags: c#, regex, silverlight-4.0

I'm using below regular expression for Dataform field for checking whether the entered text starts with `http://` or `https://` or `\\`

I'm using **System.componentmodel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute**

```
 [Display(Name = "URL", Description = "URL")]
 [RegularExpression(@"^(http[s]{0,1}:\/\/|\\\\)", 
 ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Url or filepath")]
 public string URL { get; set; }
```

but in dataform field it is throwing error if any text is enetered after **http://** or **https://** or **\\**

```
http://google.com     ---failed
https://aa        --failed
\\a         ----failed
```

I just want to pass all the above scenarios ...on  high level the regular expression should just only check whether entered text **starts** with `http://` or `https://` or `\\`

And even dataform is throwing error for the field when user enters and delete the text and click on tab.the error is **URL is required field**, but I didn't mention required attribute for this property.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a literal string, but you're trying to escape it.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(http[s]{0,1}:\/\/|\\\\)",
```

A literal string starts with `@"..."` and don't need to be escaped. So either use

```
[RegularExpression("^(http[s]{0,1}://|[\\\\]{2})(?:[\\w][\\w.-]?)",
```

or

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(http[s]{0,1}://|[\\]{2})(?:[\w][\w.-]?)",
```

**Update:**
You can also read more about string literals on MSDN: [String Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**Update 2:** It is a common error, and / doesn't have to be escaped in C# neither, it is the perl syntax. 
In perl (and PHP which uses perl regex estension, all the preg_xxx methods), one has to set a delimiter. In this languages the regex will begin with a delimiter, which is an symbol that shows the begin and the end of the regex pattern, i.e.

`/^(http[s]?:\/\/... /i` The first / is a delimiter, that's why // from http:// has to be escaped.

`#^(http[s]?://... #i` The first # is now the delimiter, that's why // from http:// doesn't have to be escaped. The instruction after the delimiter (i.e. i in this case) just tells to do a case insensitive match

Some example I used to test it:

```
        string[] inputs = { @"http://google.com", @"https://aa", @"\\a", @"\\\a" };
        Regex regEx = new Regex(@"^(http[s]{0,1}://|[\\]{2})(?:[\w][\w.-]?)+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        foreach(var input in inputs) {
            var match = regEx.Match(input);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:\t{1} => {2}", input, match.Success, match.Success?match.Groups[1].Value:string.Empty));
        }
```

The `(?:[\w][\w.-]?)+` at the end is to make sure, it that a word followed by a words, i.e \\a shouldn't be valid, neither should `http://.somedomain.com`

Result:

```
http://google.com:      True
https://aa:     True
\\a:    True
\\\a:   False
```

Comment: Tseng: You are incorrect: the literal @ is for C# compiler the four slashes at the end are needed for you regex.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll update the post and also add a special case for `\\\a` which is not correctly matched by neither of the reg ex patterns so far

Comment: Maybe you could explain what kind of error it throws? When used in Code with Regex class all of the above code works fine

Answer (score 0):

They didn't fail for me. I checked it with RegEx.IsMatch().

But if you want to check for a double \ at the beginning your regex should be ^(http[s]{0,1}://|\\)

You can try

```
^(http[s]?://|\\\\)
```

which is actually equal to your Regex.

When you want the regex to be capital insensitive use:

```
(?i)^(http[s]?://|\\\\)
```

or

```
(?i)^(http[s]?://|\\\\).+$
```

---

Addition:

I have tried this in my MVC 4 application and it works:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the website.
    /// </summary>
    [RegularExpression(@"(?i)^(http[s]?://|\\\\).+$", ErrorMessage = "Not good website")]
    public string Website { get; set; }
```

Isn't your input somehow scrumbled. I know PHP has a feature that adds magic quotes....

Comment: shiv455 Are you using capitals?

Comment: no when I use http://goo ,https://fg or \\a ,it fails in all 3 scenarios basically if we enter even a single letter after these words it throws error

Comment: @Dev.Japp ur last solution works for me ^(http[s]?://|\\\\).+$ but the issue is when I enter any invalid input and click tab the error is thrown which is expected and later when I enter blank text in the field it is throwing error after tabbing the error is "URL field is required",but I haven't specified the property as required.

Comment: shiv455 I have tested it for myself also, it appears the RegularExpressionAttribute expect an regular expression that match all content, not only the start of your content. I wonder if it is by design...
Your required field message appears weird. The only thing I can think of this moment is whether is obliged in your data model? Are you using EF?

Comment: Dev actually there is another field  [Display(Name = "ImageURI", Description = "Image URI")]
[RegularExpression(@"([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)", ErrorMessage = "Please enter exact format of Image URI for example(xxx.jpg)")]
public string ImageURI { get; set; },for this filed it was working as expected ie its not throwing error for blank text, not sure whether its issue with regex

Comment: I can leave the field blank (in the example above) and save it successfully. So I don't expect the RegularExpressionAttribute to cause the exception. Can you debug the save action? i.e. can you get more information why the error is thrown?

Comment: actually I have cleaned and rebuild the app its working fine...can u modify the regex to accept http:// or https:// or \\  ,right now these were throwing error...anyway thanks for ur solution

Comment: @shiv455 if use @"(?i)^(http[s]?://|\\\\).*$" it will also accepts input like http:// and https://

Comment: shiv455 I don't think the RegularExpressionAttribute is raising that error. Try to find out what code is generating that error.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to find a lot of regex expressions in [library](http://regexlib.com/).
E.g.: [for your task](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=301).